# Google maps API javascript no aparece con Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Buenas estoy tratando de implementar un mapa de la Javascript google maps API pero con AngularJS.

El problema es que en la página que debería aparecer el mapa no aparece.
Y la consola de google no me devuelve ningún error, incluso los logs para verificar que se esten alcanzando los controladores y ejecutando el código se imprimen.

Archivos:

`mapController.js`, `styles.css` , `map.html` en este orden.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router']);

app.controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', '$state', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state){

  console.log("carga mapCtrl al principio");

 var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }
  /** agregue esto 09/07/2019 22:39 para que se ejecute la funcion al cargarse el controlador**/

initMap(); 

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }

  console.log("carga mapCtrl al final");
}]);
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: lightgrey;
      }
   
   
#map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> deberia aparecer el mapa...</h1>
<div ng-controller="mapCtrl" id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MI-API-KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

si miro la consola de google veo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otras aclaraciones: Aquí he simplificado código a solo los archivos que comprenden el funcionamiento del mapa. Pero vale destacar que el div id map, Se encuentra en un archivo `app.html` que se ejecuta dentro `index.html` a través de un controlador de estados `ui-router`. De igual manera desde el login y hasta donde debería ejecutarse el mapa no se muestra ningun error en la consola de google.

Gracias

PD: Cosas que he intentado:

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738512/angularjs-google-map-api-integration**

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090622/how-use-initial-google-map-in-angularjs-controller/38191188**

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335835/how-does-the-google-maps-api-work-with-angularjs?rq=1**

y algunas variaciones realizadas por mi.

Comment: ¿Has intentado darle una altura en pixels?

Comment: Si lo he intentado, tambien en otras unidades de medida como em, vh, etc

Comment: ¿En qué momento llamas a la función initMap?

Comment: Con el callback del script de google. En tiempos de ejecución T0 carga el html, T1 scripts, etc T2 el callback. Tambien usé un ng-init="initMap()" porque tambien llegue a pensar que no se ejecutaba la función pero tampoco hubo caso

Comment: Efectivamente no estaba llamando a la funcion... asique agregue al final de la funcion initMap ´initMap();´ para que se auto ejecute al cargar el controlador. pero ahora me dice que " angular.js:15567 ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at initMap (mapController.js:10) "

Comment: @Macali la solución no va en la pregunta, para eso tienes la zona de respuestas en la parte inferior de la página

Comment: eso es seguro? ya una vez respondí mi pregunta y me dijeron que debía ponerlo al final del post. pero lo cambio gracias

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo que hice para solucionar fue mover el script con la API Key de google a mi estado padre en `index.html` y borrar el parametro `&callback=initMap` que viene por defecto porque me daba un error de `Promise` ya que aun no estaba cargado el controlador que contiene la función `initMap()`.

Luego me di cuenta que function `initMap` no aparecía en el scope de mi estado en `map.html` y lo cambie por `$scope.initMap = function() {...}`. Luego desde mi estado `map` hice lo siguiente.

```
<div ng-controller="mapCtrl">
    <div id="map" style="display: flex;">
        <button ng-click="initMap()" style="margin: auto;">Activar mapa</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Entonces al presionar sobre mi botón "Activar mapa" llamo a la función `initMap();` que ahora si se encuentra en el scope.

Si a alguien le interesa que el mapa se ejecute inmediatamente se carga el estado o la página. pueden utilizar `<div ng-init="initMap()"></div>` de esta manera al cargarse este fragmento de código en el DOM se debería ejecutar el mapa.